# Отбивка по левому краю?

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Добрый день,

наверное, глупый вопрос ) но можете подсказать, что означает сделать отбивку по левому краю? 
Попросили сделать для "Find a date today" и "Search radius".
Не понимаю, просто прилепить к левому краю? Или что сделать требуется?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю просят сделать "выравнивание по левому краю". Просят для обоих блоков текста? Возможно заказчик хочет видеть эти надписи на одном уровне по вертикали по левому краю... Действительно надпись "Search radius" слегка выбивается из общего макета.